# spark repl "type mismatch" for inner class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, inner-classes, spark-repl

I have define some trait and class in spark program, it works well when packaged into a jar, but if execute in spark repl, it will fail.

```
trait Builder {
  trait Layer {
    def layerSize: Int
  }

  abstract class Layer1 extends Layer

  class Layer2(val layerName: String) extends Layer {
    override def layerSize: Int = 10
    def addInput(from: Layer): String = {
      ""
    }
  }

  object Layer2  {
    def apply(name: String): Layer2 = {
      new Layer2(name)
    }
  }

  val FEATURES: Layer = new Layer1 {
    override val layerSize = 10
  }
}

class aBuilder extends Builder
```

then i run the code :

```
  val builder = new aBuilder
  val test = builder.Layer2("")
  test.addInput(builder.FEATURES)
```

it error with:

```
<console>:32: error: type mismatch;
 found   : builder.Layer
 required: builder.Layer
                test.addInput(builder.FEATURES)
```

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov In Spark REPL or standard Scala / sbt?

Comment: @zero323 Holy crap, I thought he said *Scala REPL*. Take that back. It works in the Scala REPL/SBT.

Comment: @zero323 Hmm.. seems to work in the Spark REPL as well.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Can I borrow yours? :D It works just fine for me in plain sbt but fails in Spark :/

Comment: @zero323 Which spark version are you running with?

Comment: Actually, it works just in standard REPL but not with spark-shell (1.6.0)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I tested 1.6 with Scala 2.11, 1.6.1 official binaries (Scala 2.10) and 2.0.0-preview. I think it is related to  SPARK-2620 but cannot prove that.

Comment: @zero323 I'm running Spark 1.6.1 with official binaries (Scala 2.10) and this works for me.

Comment: I use spark 1.6.1 with scala 2.10 and in spark shell repl.it's all right in scala repl.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the following seems to work with spark 1.6.0 and official binaries (scala 2.10)

```
scala> trait Builder {
     |   trait Layer {
     |     def layerSize: Int
     |   }
     | 
     |   abstract class Layer1 extends Layer
     | 
     |   class Layer2(val layerName: String) extends Layer {
     |     override def layerSize: Int = 10
     |     def addInput(from: Layer): String = {
     |       ""
     |     }
     |   }
     | 
     |   object Layer2  {
     |     def apply(name: String): Layer2 = {
     |       new Layer2(name)
     |     }
     |   }
     | 
     |   val FEATURES: Layer = new Layer1 {
     |     override val layerSize = 10
     |   }
     | }
// defined trait Builder

scala> class aBuilder extends Builder
// defined class aBuilder

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)
val builder = new aBuilder
val test = builder.Layer2("")
test.addInput(builder.FEATURES)
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
// builder: aBuilder = $iwC$$iwC$aBuilder@8f2513c
// test: builder.Layer2 = $iwC$$iwC$Builder$Layer2@561b39f4
// res0: String = ""
```

Nevertheless, I'm not sure if it's a variant of the following issue : [SPARK-5149](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5149).